# How can an object await different requests depending on its state?

Tags: c++, class, object, interface

My `Controller` class manipulates some `Object` through its public methods. Here's the problem: certain `Object` changes requested by the `Controller` can turn out to need some clarification before any further manipulations are performed. **How can it be cleanly solved?** Here's a straight-forward implementation to make the problem more understandable:

```
class Object {
 public:
  std::optional<Clarification_request> process_request(Parameter);
  // USE THIS ONLY IF process_request() RETURNED A CLARIFICATION REQUEST:
  void clarify_previous(Clarification);
};
```

Is there a cleaner design decision? Here's my idea (which you maybe shouldn't read before coming up with your own if you'd like to):

```
class Object {
 public:
  std::variant<Usual_request, Clarification_request> get_awaited_request() const;
  void process_request(std::variant<Parameter, Clarification>);
};
```

However, it still doesn't seem close to a great solution. Any better ones?